# SysTick Timer in ARM arch - Mazidi book part

Tags: c, embedded

In mazidi book ARM arch. , using the sysTick Counter... i read this part

> Program 5-1 loads the initial value to the maximum and dumps the
>   current value of the SysTick on LEDs of PORTF as it counts down. On TI
>   ARM LaunchPad, we cannot see the lower 16 bits since it is counting
>   down every 62.5 nsec (1/16MHz=62.5). It takes the lower 16-bits 65536
>   x 62.5ns= 0.4096 ms to overflow to the upper 8-bits. That is the
>   reason we shift it right 20 times.

and here is the code

```
#include "TM4C123GH6PM.h"
int main (void)
{
int x;
/* enable clock to GPIOF at clock gating control register */
SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |= 0x20;
/* enable the GPIO pins for the LED (PF3, 2 1) as output */
GPIOF->DIR = 0x0E;
/* enable the GPIO pins for digital function */
GPIOF->DEN = 0x0E;
/* Configure SysTick */
SysTick->LOAD = 0xFFFFFF; /* reload reg. with max value */
SysTick->CTRL = 5; /* enable it, no interrupt, use system clock */
while (1)
{
x = SysTick->VAL; /* read current value of down counter */
x = x >> 20; /* shift right to slow down the rate */
GPIOF->DATA = x; /* dump it to the LEDs */
}
}
/* This function is called by the startup assembly code to perform system specific
initialization tasks. */
void SystemInit(void)
{
__disable_irq(); /* disable all IRQs */
/* Grant coprocessor access */
/* This is required since TM4C123G has a floating point coprocessor */
SCB->CPACR |= 0x00F00000;
}
```

My question is regarding the part inside the while(1)
I still cannot see how does shifting right `x = x >> 20;` can slow the rate so we can see the LEDs" ??
and why did he exactly choose to shift 20 times ?!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: This is a crude timer controlled blinky example.

Comment: I have edited my questions, my problem is exactly in the shifting part, how do we slow the rate of the blinking so we can see it by shifting right (x = x >> 20;) ??

Comment: How fast would the LEDs change if he didn't do the right shift? I'd guess every 62.5ns

Answer (score 0):

Elementary math:

Assuming SysTick runs at 16MHz, the `x = x >> 20;` is the same as
`x = x / 1048576` or roughly "divide by a million".

So you end up changing the Port value about every 1/16th of a second - which yields a nice 8Hz blinking LED - or would if they actually used pin 0 as an output.

Since the first LED seems to be at pin 1 and that pin sees excactly half the frequency, it will blink about 4Hz. The second and 3rd will blink at 2 and 1Hz respectively.